# How to get one middle position for my inputs and span be on left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to get one middle position for my inputs and all span be on left.

I want my inputs be on a middle of page .
another span (left/right) will match for input lane

I use some classes from bootstrap-4

CSS

```
span {
    color: oldlace;
}

input {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
    <form (submit)="submit()">

      <div id="egg" class="invisible">
        <span class="p-1">Egg</span>
        <input class="text-center rounded-pill border border-danger p-1 m-1" type="number" title="Egg" name="egg"
          placeholder="gram" [(ngModel)]="protein.egg">
        <!-- <span class="p-1"> size</span><br> -->
      </div>

      <div id="bread" class="invisible">
        <span class="p-1">Bread</span>
        <input class="text-center rounded-pill border border-danger p-1 m-1" type="number" title="Bread" name="bread"
          placeholder="gram" [(ngModel)]="protein.bread">
        <!-- <span class="p-1"> slices , 30g pre slice</span><br> -->
      </div>

    </form>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can apply same width for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply width in `span`

```css
.spanE {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<form (submit)="submit()">
 <div id="egg" class="invisible">
  <span class="p-1 spanE">Egg</span>
  <input class="text-center rounded-pill border border-danger p-1 m-1" type="number" title="Egg" name="egg"
  placeholder="gram" [(ngModel)]="protein.egg">
  <!-- <span class="p-1"> size</span><br> -->
 </div>

 <div id="bread" class="invisible">
  <span class="p-1 spanE">Bread</span>
  <input class="text-center rounded-pill border border-danger p-1 m-1" type="number" title="Bread" name="bread"
  placeholder="gram" [(ngModel)]="protein.bread">
  <!-- <span class="p-1"> slices , 30g pre slice</span><br> -->
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: work perfectly  , why display: inline-block; must for fix it?

Comment: span is inline element and for applying width, you need block property so inline-block property works fine here.

Comment: oh cool thanks , you offer maybe change this span element to something else?

Comment: you can use label here instead of span

Comment: Hope you like my answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use the tablet in a one column
Input Field name and second column input fied

Comment: You can be more specific?